# how to get the values from hash map and put them in array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, hashmap

I am trying to pull the values from hash map and put them in array, but I keep getting a null pointer exception.

Is there any other way to do this?

```
//some code....
String n[]=new String[tcur.getCount()];;
String t[]=new String[tcur.getCount()];;
HashMap<Integer, String> typehashmap=new HashMap<Integer, String>();
HashMap<Integer, String> namehashmap=new HashMap<Integer, String>();

//some code..
String   type[]=typehashmap.keySet().toArray(new String[typehashmap.size()]);
String   name[]=namehashmap.keySet().toArray(new String[namehashmap.size()]);          


for (int i=0;i<=type.length;i++) {
    n[i]=namehashmap.get(nameiterator[i]).toString();
    System.out.println(n[i]);
    t[i]=typehashmap.get(typeiterator[i]).toString();
    System.out.println (t[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use this?

```
 Set<Integer> keys = namehashmap.keySet();
 Collection<String> values = namehashmap.values();
```

You can work with values collection many ways.

```
 for(String value:values) { ... }
```

If you still want arrays, maybe you want do:

```
 keys.toArray();
 values.toArray();
```

Comment: through view holder class I have to print them in list view in android which requires an array.if you could tell the way to change collection into array.that would do too.kindly help.

Comment: You got in answer, keys.toArray() and values.toArray() ;)

Comment: Object[] n=names.toArray();   
error-->Object[] t= types.toArray();
why is it so second line is giving compile time error though I have string type of values in both the collection

Comment: Cast it: (String[])types.toArray();

Comment: isn't there any way to convert hashmap directly into array of string

Answer (score 0):

Real question is, what do you try to accomplish? Are your two HashMaps interconnected, say entries with the same integer key in both maps belong together? If so, I would first consider making a wrapper class for this e.g.:

```
private static class TypeName {
   private String type;
   private String name;
}
```

And using a HashMap

Furthermore, IMHO the best way to iterate over a HashMap is to use the entry set:

```
Map<A,B> map = new HashMap<A,B>();
for(Entry<A,B> entry : map.entrySet()) {
   A a = entry.getKey();
   B b = entry.getValue();
   // do things
}
```